# Unable write current date to the HDFS directory

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, put

I want to write current date to a file in HDFS, so that i can read it for next run.
Eg: from the below command i want to write ***2021-08-03 08:43:37*** to HDFS directory /user/maria_dev/satheesh/temp. I tried below, but didn't work. Any suggestions please?

`` echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | hadoop fs -put - /user/maria_dev/satheesh/temp ``

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: There is no error, its adding - to hdfs location.

Comment: It is not recommended to store such small files in HDFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is wring the date to the HDFS directory using put command and - as file name. When I do cat I am getting the date.

`` echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | hadoop fs -put - /user/maria_dev/satheesh/temp' ``

`[maria_dev@sandbox-hdp ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/maria_dev/satheesh/temp/*`

***Output:*** 2021-08-03 08:39:58